# does anybody know slicing effect for iphone + cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

in my game i want to give slicing effect , like after moving my finger on monster it should  kill and monster  blood  should come on screen ,and disappear after few seconds ..

please help me ..

help will be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this tutorial :- http://blog.roychowdhury.org/2010/11/19/cocos2d-iphone-tutorial-die-grossini-die-part-i/ they create blood particle effect manually

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MotionStreakTest example coming with cocos2d. I Think you can create your own effect based on this.

Or take a look at particle effects. Create a blood emitter and move it with your finger